# Use jQuery .find() result as argument in callback function in chain

Tags: jquery, find

I have this problem (is it now?):

Let's have this HTML:

```
<div>
 <p></p>
 <p id="bar"></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p id="foo"></p>
 <p id="baz"></p>
</div>
```

simple.

In jQuery, we have function (e.g. 'click') added to all divs:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).doSomething($(this))
  .find('#baz')
    .doSomethingWithCallback ({args}, callbackFunction($FIND_RESULT) );
});
```

Obviously, variable $FIND_RESULT doesn't exist – I would like to know **how can I get to result of last .find() query?**

Is there any way, or do I have to break *my mad chain* (or repeat $(this).find() as argument)?

**Edit**: IRL example:

```
function hide($div) { $div.css({'display': 'none'});

function ...
  $(this)
    .anyFunction()
  .find('.foo')
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 250, hide(^that^));
 }
```

Comment: What kind of functions are `doSomething` and `doSomethingWithCallback`? Could you give some real life examples?

Comment: I don't really understand this question. Are you trying to pass the result of a `.find()` as an argument to another function?

Comment: added doSomething IRL :)

Comment: Jasie: yes. Maybe the subset wasn't the right word, since I basically do another query over the children of elements in $(this)?

Comment: Can't you use .find('.foo').each(function(){$(this).animate(x,x, hide(this));});

Answer (score 1):

Generally with jQuery functions, your doSomethingWithCallback will be executed multiple times one for each match of find(), and therefore your callback method will be called one time for each match too, so passing the set of elements is innecesary, use $(this).

Comment: I'm sorry... what? $(this) actually contains entirely different items. And I know that my callback will be called multiple times, that's the point (although in my actual case right now, I'm 100% sure that there's always only one item after .find() )

Comment: So you want to get the full subset of items returned by find() in your callback?

Comment: yes, I want the everything last .find() query returned to be used as argument in my callback :)

Comment: You'll need to save the result of find before or doing another find inside the callback. Depending the number of elements to match it will not be that critical on performance. Just pass the find string to the callback.

Another solution is to modify the .animate function to call the callback passing the received find result, you can do this by hooking that function, if you're interested in that way i can make an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused also.  The .find() method is extremely robust, so are all the other jQuery functions.  Each one executes on a group of elements and then passes those elements back so that other functions can chain on them.  http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/DXbXU/

On your custom function, are you returning the objects after you process them? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for jQuery's

## [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

?

If you're making you own plugins then take a look at [`pushSack()`](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/) and [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

```
function ...
  $(this)
    .anyFunction()
  .find('.foo')
  .end()  // <---
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 250, hide(^that^));
 }
```